# Display ArrayList contents in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, arraylist, joptionpane

First of all I found some examples that work the way I want with a standard array how ever I need to use an ArrayList as the size is not limited. And the contents are add via different methods.

My problem is tring to get the Arraylist contents to display and on its own line.
With my code bellow only the last content is display.

NOTE: This is not the actual application it is only a test program their for I have a filler method.

PS, Any assitance will be greatly apreceated. I have reseched this For the last 2 hours.

Here is the what I have done so far.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.*;

   public class fe
  {
    private static ArrayList<String> errorCache = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static String details;

   public fe()
    {
    }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    fillList(); 
    showMessage();
   }

  private static void showMessage()
   {
    for (int i=0;i<errorCache.size();i++)
    {
        details =  errorCache.get(i);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, details, "Printing results",  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }

  private static void fillList()
  {
    errorCache.add("this");
    errorCache.add("should");
    errorCache.add("bee");
    errorCache.add("on");
    errorCache.add("its");
    errorCache.add("own");
    errorCache.add("line");
  }
}
```

I got this to work thats to all that help I spent ages trying work this out.
the end code it the result for anyone else that has problems with this.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.*;

   public class fe
    {
     private static ArrayList<String> errorCache = new ArrayList<String>();

   public fe()
    {
    }

   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      fillList(); 
      showMessage();
    }

   private static void showMessage()
   {
      String details = "";
      for (int i=0;i<errorCache.size();i++)
    {
        details +=  errorCache.get(i) + "\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, details, "Printing results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Remimues way.
    //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<html>"); 
    //for (int i = 0; i < errorCache.size(); i++) {
    //builder.append(errorCache.get(i));
    //builder.append("<br>");
    // }
     //builder.append("</html>");
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
     //(null, builder.toString(), "Printing results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

     }

    private static void fillList()
    {
        errorCache.add("this");
        errorCache.add("should");
        errorCache.add("bee");
        errorCache.add("on");
        errorCache.add("its");
        errorCache.add("own");
        errorCache.add("line");
     }
  }
```

Comment: You probably meant `details += errorCache.get(i);`

Comment: assylias that sort of works tho It's all on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the use of HTML for formatting and `StringBuilder` for performance:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<html>"); 
for (int i = 0; i < errorCache.size(); i++) {
    builder.append(errorCache.get(i));
    builder.append("<br>");
}
builder.append("</html>");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null, builder.toString(), "Printing results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Fewer objects are created when using `StringBuilder` compared to using `String` concatentation `+=` gives better performance (not noticeable for small number of Strings) but good practice nonetheless

Comment: From your comment above, assumed that you didnt want it all on the same line. If you don't simply remove the HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
  private static void showMessage(){
      String details = "";

      for( int i=0; i < errorCache.size(); i++ ){
          details +=  errorCache.get(i) + " ";
      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, details, "Printing results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
  }
```

Comment: I tried what Assylias said with adding + "\n" on the end which seeems to work the it prints null at the start.

Comment: Got I moved the string details to showMessage() method and it removes the null.